# Show that $A \cdot \textbf{0}_{n \times p}=\textbf{0}_{m \times p}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$. Show that $A \cdot \textbf{0}_{n \times p}=\textbf{0}_{m \times p}$ **without** computing individual entries.
You can use that $\mathbb{F}^{r \times s}$ forms a vector space for all integers $r, s \geq 1$.

This is a no brainer question if we could compute the entries individually. But I can't get my head around as to how we can do this without component by component calculation. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Maybe $AA = AA$ so $A (A-A) = A0 = 0$?

Comment: Maybe you need to say something about how the image of the $\mathbf{0}$ matrix has to be just $\{0\}$. And then of course $A$ sends $0$ to $0$? If this is homework, it probably depends on what you just learned...

Comment: @copper.hat ... if $m=n=p$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to use the algebraic properties of matrices, then observe that:
$$A0 = A(0+0) = A0 + A0$$

Since $\mathbb{F}^{r \times s}$ is a vector space, an additive inverse $-(A0)$ exists. Hence:
$$A0 = A0 + 0 =  A0 + (A0+(-A0)) = (A0+A0)+(-A0) = A0+(-A0) = 0$$
as was desired.

Comment: @Prem OP wrote specifically that "You can use that $\mathbb{F}^{r\times s}$ forms a vector space for all integers $r,s\geq 1$."

Comment: It's not circular at all; there's nothing about the axioms of a vector space which talk about multiplication of two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use $0$ to mean either the LHS Zero Matrix or the RHS Zero Matrix, with Correct Size.

$A(0) = A(0+0) = A(0)+A(0)$
[[ This is because 0+0=0 & Multiplication is Distributive over Addition ]]

$A(0)-A(0) = A(0)$
[[ This is by adding $-A(0)$ to LHS & RHS ]]

$0=A(0)$
[[ This is by using $X-X = 0$ on LHS ]]

$A0=0$
[[ This is by exchanging LHS & RHS ]]

We use Minimal Properties in this Derivation.

Comment: This proof uses the same argument as @MordeusMorgenstern, arranged differently. Cyclic arguments are no problem in any of the answers, because $\mathbb{F}^{r\times s}$ being a vector space is not concerned with matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

> $A \cdot \textbf{0}_{n \times p}=\textbf{0}_{m \times p}$

For all $v\neq 0$ $A\cdot \textbf{0}_{n \times p} v =0$ and then use the uniqueness of the zero element.

Comment: No it's using associativity. $(A0)v=A(0v)=0$.

Comment: The terms $A0$ only look equal, but are in fact not the same. In the question the 0 stood for the n by p matrix with all zeroes. In Suzu's answer, when $A0$ occurs the second time (as you correctly point out), it stands for the zero vector of p-dimensional space.
It is a short deduction to show that a matrix maps the zero vector always to the zero vector.

Comment: Sounds good, @8bc3457f , but a Doubt : How do we conclude $(0v)=0$ without calculating the elements component by component ( which OP forbids ) ? We have converted Matrix Issue into Vector Issue. Maybe , we should go further , to convert this Vector Issue into Scalar Issue by $|0v|=|0||v|=0$ !!

Comment: I expect that using $0v=0$ is permitted in the OP's situation. Nevertheless here an algebraic proof: $0v = (0+0)v = 0v + 0v$ so by eliminating $0v$ once, we obtain $0 = 0v$ as we wanted. (Here I used "0" for both the zero vector and for the zero matrix.)

Comment: Applying a norm to the vectors should be avoided in this situation, because this is imposes additional structure on the vector spaces which isn't always available. The first equality of your argument using the norm is only a $\le$-inequality in general. But that's no problem here. On the other hand a pedantic reader might interpret the "0 !!" at the end as a double factorial (0!!=1) which would make your proof wrong ;)

Comment: Co-incidentally , your Vector Case "0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v" is the Exact Mirror Image of my Answer in Matrix Case "A0=A(0+0)=A0+A0" [[ Nice Catch about "!!" ]] & thanks for clarifying my Doubts @8bc3457f

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here, $v$ is any vector which may be operated on by the linear zero operator, and we get zero out of that operation. The "zero" on the right is a generic thing which corresponds to whatever $v$ might be, and we know from the properties of the zero operator that $0v=0$. Then just use associativity to see that $A(0v)=(A0)v=0$ and so $A0$ must also be a zero (null) operator.